# Choose 3 items from a list of 5, with indistinguishable items

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm stuck on a simple counting principle. Say there is a list of 5 items, aaabb, where the a's are indistinguishable and the b's are indistinguishable.

How many ways can I choose 3 items (order doesn't matter)? Well, it would be:

aaa, aab, abb

How can I get this using combinations? If I do 5C3, then there's no way I can get to 3. If I use constructive counting, it's also wrong:

(5 ways to choose first item * 4 ways to choose second item * 3 ways to choose third item) / (3 duplicate a's * 2 duplicate b's). This gives us the answer 10.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case of picking $k$ items, we can pick any of $0,1,2,3$ 'a' items, and any of $0,1,2$ 'b' items.

We can represent this using a polynomial called a generating function:

$$P(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2)$$

Multiplying this out gives:

$$P(x)=1+2x+3x^2+3x^3+2x^4+x^5$$
$P(x)$ can also be written as:

$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^5 a_k x^k$$
In your case we have $k=3$, so we look at the coefficient of $x^3$, which is $a_3$ and equals $3$. The contributions to this from the original definition of $P(x)$ are $x\cdot x^2, x^2\cdot x, x^3\cdot1$, and these correspond to $abb,aab,aaa$.

If you had picked $k=4$ balls, the answer would have been the coefficient of $x^4$, i.e. $2$. These are namely $aaab$ and $aabb$, which come from $x^3\cdot x$ and $x^2\cdot x^2$ respectively.